# How do I use vector::push_back() on a vector of a user defined type to only modify one object?

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

How do I use the push_back() function on a vector of a user defined type, preferably to modify one object, to clarify:

```
class words{

public:

  string noun;

  string verb;

  string adj;

  string adv;

};
```

and the vector:

```
vector <word> v;
```

Now Lets assume the user inputs a sentence, and I divide it into words, and for whatever reason I need it sorted out into a vector of the type word, not of the type string, how do I go about doing that?
I need to use push_back() because the vector is currently empty, and I want to add a new container.
I don't think I made myself clear (sorry about that, I'm new here), I want to modify the objects separately, so for example I want to set

```
v[2].noun = "shark";
```

but just setting that would call a range error, so I need something else.

Comment: Well, you construct a `words` and push it into `v`?

Comment: The purpose of `push_back` is to insert new elements, not to modify elements of the vector.

Comment: What have you tried? How did that work, or not work? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as the same way you do with another types....

suppose you have the constructor:

```
words(string noun, string verb, string adj, string adv) : noun(noun), verb(verb), adj(adj), adv(adv) { }
```

then declare the vector 
and add some objects of class word...

```
vector <words> v;
words w1("Car", "wash", "beautiful", "carefully");
v.push_back(w1);
```